# Error response from daemon: Invalid container name (tomcat:8.0), only [a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_.-] are allowed

Tags: docker, vagrant

I'm trying to run a docker container by Vagrant Docker provision:

```
d.run "tomcat:8.0", args: "-it -d -p 8888:8888 --name tomcat8"
```

Vagrant pulls the image fine, but when it comes to running the container I get a:

> Error response from daemon: Invalid container name (tomcat:8.0), only
>   [a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_.-] are allowed

I would like to keep the `:8.0` so that I'm sure I run the right image version.

Comment: As the error says, `:` is not a valid character in a container name (whether you like it or not). You could switch to a different naming convention like `tomcat_v8.0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it turned out that Vagrant by default uses the image name as container name even if I used the `--name` arg.

In my case that was unfortunate since I was pulling from the official Tomcat repository at Dockerhub and hence could not change the image name.

What I found was that Vagrant has an extra setting called `auto_assign_name` which must be set to `false` in order to use the `--name` arg.

So a working Vagrant line would be:

```
d.run "tomcat:8.0", args: "-it -p 8080:8080 --name tomcat8", auto_assign_name: false
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the error came in Docker when I was trying to setup a Dockerfile with an image tag.

I was setting it like this:

```yaml
version: '3.8'

services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: easypanel-nextjs:0.0.1
    container_name: nextjs-sqlite
    env_file:
      - .env.production
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    volumes:
      - ./data:/data
```

What worked was moving `image` above `build`. Weird af error.

```yaml
version: '3.8'

services:
  web:
    image: easypanel-nextjs:0.0.1
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: nextjs-sqlite
    env_file:
      - .env.production
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    volumes:
      - ./data:/data
```

The error was for posterity sake:

> 0.0s Error response from daemon: Invalid container name (nextjs-sqlite:0.0.1), only [a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_.-] are allowed